# Adding an underscore to a char in a string

Tags: javascript, extjs

Let's say I have this string: Transplantation.

If I want to underscore the first letter, which is the letter 'T', I can do it like this:

```
string text = "Transplantation";
underscoredText = '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">'+text.charAt(0)+'</span>'+text.substring(1, text.length);
```

Now what can I do if I want an underscore on the letter 'n'?

What I tried is this:

```
underscoredText = '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">'+text.charAt(3)+'</span>'+text.substring(1, text.length);
```

But this is totally wrong, since I only make the char at index 3 to appear as the first letter in the string, så the text now looks like this: nransplantation (and the underscore is still on the forst letter (at index 0), which is now n instead of T.

Lacking experience with programming, I'd also like to know whether this seems like a bad way of doing what I'm trying to do. The reason I am doing this, is because I want to show users what keys can be used as hotkeys/shortcuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the letter in a variable, say:

```
var hotkey = "n";
```

...then you can use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to insert the `span`:

```
underscoredText = text.replace(hotkey, '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">$&</span>');
```

The `$&` in the replacement string says "put the text that matched here." `replace` will only replace the first instance (when called as above, using a string as the first argument).

Although I guess just reusing `hotkey` would be just as good:

```
underscoredText = text.replace(hotkey, '<span style="text-decoration: underline;">' + hotkey + '</span>');
```

> I'd also like to know whether this seems like a bad way of doing what I'm trying to do.

I would use a class rather than inline styling:

```
underscoredText = text.replace(hotkey, '<span class="hotkey">$&</span>');
```

Separately, underlined text on web pages usually indicates links. While I don't think it would be confusing in this case, you might consider boldface or (if it's a menu) explicitly listing the key sequence next to it.

---

Gratuitous live example:

```js
var text = "Transplantation";
var hotkey = "n";
var underscoredText = text.replace(hotkey, '<span class="hotkey">$&</span>');
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", underscoredText);
```

```css
.hotkey {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and very helpful solution @T.J Crowder

I am wondering. Won't this solution become a problem if there appeared another n before the n I wish to target? Let's say the text is Trnansplantation. Notice the n at index 2. This is not a typo, and I know that no such word exist. It's just as an example. Won't the above solution target the n at index 2, when in fact we want to target the n at index 4 (in the text "Trnansplantation")

Comment: @MOR_SNOW: Yes, it would. You didn't say anything about skipping some. Normally with this sort of thing, you underscore the first one (though I can see a scenario where one of them is in the middle of a syllable and a later one starts a syllable, where it would make sense to underscore the later one). In that case, you go back to string concatenation: `str.substring(0, indexOfChar) + beginningOfSpan + str.substring(indexOfChar, 1) + endOfSpan + substring(indexOfChar + 1);`